# Category of torsion free abelian groups is additive but not abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, abelian-groups, abelian-categories, additive-categories

I’m trying to prove that the category of torsion free abelian groups is additive but not abelian…
To prove that it is not abelian I’m trying to prove that that the multiplication map φ x2 in Z is not a kernel. So we suppose that it is a kernel of a map f. If f is not zero I’m having a trouble proving that this is not possible so that f=0.
And on proving that it is additive I don’t know how to work…

Comment: This idea should work, i.e. looking at $\varphi:\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z$ via $x\mapsto 2x$. This is a monomorphism, and so if the category were abelian then $\varphi$ would be the kernel of some map. Say it's the kernel of $f:\mathbb Z\to A$. But then $f(2x)=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb Z$. This should contradict the torsion free part, but how?

Comment: Maybe we can write f(2x)=2xf(1)=0? And since f is not zero than f(1) is it zero so this is a contradiction?

Comment: In fact, the monomorphism $x \mapsto 2x:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ is also an epimorphism, but not an isomorphism, so the category of torsion-free abelian groups is not balanced.

Comment: Sorry I now started a homological algebra lesson so I don’t know what balanced category is… Can you explain me more?

Comment: And what about additivity?

Comment: Yeah $f$ is nonzero, so $f(1)\neq 0$ but $2f(1)=0$, which contradicts $A$ being torsion free.